# API request not working on installed react native app

Tags: react-native, expo, apk, eas

I built an app using react native. I'm using axios to make API requests, the app works fine on my expo development server but after running eas build and installing the APK on my physical device, the API requests are not working at all.

I connected my device to my laptop and ran adb logcat to monitor the app, I noticed that the request weren't being made.

Comment: Hi! We need more info to see whats going on. But maybe it's something related to CORS policy. Did you try to check the connections using flipper or similar?

Comment: It's not a CORS problem. I was able to fix the issue by adding usesCleartextTraffic=true to the app.json file. Now it works perfectly on my device and a friend's but it doesn't work on the client's device. His device is the only one the app isn't working on.